# change from \n to <br> doesn't work using .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This question has been asked many times on this website, I tried many examples but nonthing worked.
My case is :

```
Info.find('description').html(Info.description);
```

I get output like this : Michelle\nma belle These are words that go together well.

I can't replace the `\n` with `<br>` (the output is for HTML page) I tried all of these options but I get the same output, do I miss something?

```
Info.find('description').html(Info.description).replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
Info.find('description').html(Info.description.replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));
Info.find('description').html(Info.description.toString().replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));)
Info.find('description').html(Info.description).replace(**"**\n**"**, **"**<br />**"**));;    
Info.find('description').html(Info.description).replace(new RegExp('/\n','g'), '<br />')
```

Comment: Use  `\r\n` in your replace

Comment: I tried that as well, Nothing...

Comment: Can you post the exact output of `Info.description`, and post enough code that we can reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add double backslash `\\` before `n`.

```
Info.find('description').html(Info.description).replace(/\\n/g, "<br>");
```

** using single backslash `\` means escaping a character in *regex*. so, you were just matching `n` instead of `\n`